# Any change in the my index.html is not reflected on webpage. Why?

Tags: html, jss

I downloaded demo version of particles.js and am trying to modify it using basic HTML . But none of the changes are getting reflected on the webpage. Is there any obvious thing which I am missing ? TIA

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en" >
 <head><meta charset="UTF-8">   <title>particles.js demo</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    </head>
 <body>
   <!-- particles.js container -->   <div id="particles-js"></div>   
   <!-- stats - count particles -->    <div class="count-particles">  

   <span class="js-count-particles">--</span> particles </div>  
   <!--particles.js lib - https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js --> 
   <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
   <!-- stats.js lib -->  
   <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

   <script  src="./script.js"></script>

   <h1 class="main-title"><a href="index.html">Hello all </a></h1>
   <p class="text-content">Welcome to my website! Click on a link to get started.</p> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://github.com/ishank4/bubbles/blob/master/index.html

Comment: Show your code you modified ?

Comment: github.com/ishank4/bubbles/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use `position: relative` to your overall container

below code will works for you ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>particles.js demo</title>



      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">


</head>

<body>

  <!-- particles.js container -->
  <div id="particles-js" class="tt"></div> 
  <!-- stats - count particles --> 
  <div class="count-particles">
  <span class="js-count-particles">--</span> particles </div>
  <!-- particles.js lib - https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js --> 
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
  <!-- stats.js lib -->
  <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>



    <script  src="./script.js"></script>
    <div class="body-container" style="position: relative;">
        <h1 class="main-title"><a href="index.html">Hgdfgdfello all </a></h1>
        <p class="text-content">Welcome to my website! Click on a link to get started.</p>
    </div>




</body>

</html>
```